# IE-Edge Compatible mode issue with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My AngularJS Web application is working fine in dev environment as expected once its deployed to higher environment . While running/browsing the application in IE Edge the application by default selecting the 8 and my application is not working since IE 8 wont support AngularJS.

So tried changing the  meta tag to override the compatible view  setting in my code as follows

Trial 1

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
      <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Here in the place of the content I tried with all possible options like
IE=edge,11,EmulateIE11,10,EmulateIE10,9,EmulateIE9

Trial 2

```
 <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
           <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
        </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

I tried in all possible ways but while browsing the application by default it is selecting the IE mode 8 and application not working.

**Note:** 
It's an intranet site with compatible settings enabled in IE. Before upgrading to IE from 10 to 11, the application was up and running correctly without any override compatibility code.

My hosted environment has compatible view settings by default so am trying to override default setting by above trials but no luck. In the Fiddler HTTP response header I can see the X-UA-Compatible edge and in view source I can see:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

FYI
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdgeLauncher/issues/14

Comment: The site is working in all browsers except EDGE

Comment: It looks like this is "Internet Explorer" running in "Edge" mode, not "Microsoft Edge" which is only available on Windows 10.

Comment: group level policies(organisation level settings for an intranet application) overrides the settings at html or webconfig or IIS responseheaders settings. Solved my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was experiencing this issue yesterday. Browsed about it for quite sometime why it was occurring. It worked good when tested with my localhost application server, but when I moved it to the server machine for intranet access, it started getting distorted in IE. I realized that whenever IE is being launched, it's launched in compatibility mode IE7 by default for all the intranet pages.

Tried with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` as the first meta tag and it worked for me.

I am glad to see that you got it worked out by getting the group policy settings updated.